# Using Lagrange Multipliers to find max/min of this function relative to a condition set (inequality)

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-topology, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

I was wondering how should I treat the inequality conditions for this exercise; to be more precise, how to form them. Is deducing from
$$
x \in [0,2] 
$$
and
$$
y\in[0,4]
$$
that $$
x+y \le 6
$$
alright? Can I use this as my condition? If so, if I begin the search on two separate case:

i) (x,y) belongs to the interior of S (x+y<6)
and

ii) (x,y) belongs to boundary of S (x+y=6) correct?

For i) I find the point for which $\nabla f = 0$ then check if it provides a min/max and for ii) I apply Lagrange multipliers theorem to find the points?

Comment: Hello :) Do you need to apply Lagrangian multipliers? For a maximum/minimum in the interior, we have $\nabla f(x, y) =0$, here you are right. On the boundary, we have ($x\in\{0, 2\}$ and $y\in[0, 4]$) or ($x\in[0, 2]$ and $y\in\{0, 4\}$).

Comment: oh, so that was I supposed to seek for in the boundary condition? it actually makes sense